# R How to import excel file with special character

Tags: r

I want to import an excel file with a special character in it's name:

`file_name✓.xlsx`

`✓`-> this check mark is the special character (Unicode= `U+2713`)

But RStudio does not recognize this special character on my Windows PC.

`read_excel("file_name✓.xlsx")` is not working.

But on Linux this code works.

What can I do to import this excel file with a special character in Windows?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `read_excel("file_name\u2713.xlsx")`?

Comment: `read_excel(file.choose())` can also be used.  `read.csv("file_name\u2713.csv")` is working in my console,  Don't know why it is not opening excel filr

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, but it gives me the same output.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I also used the `file.choose()` function but it does also not work

Comment: So the problem is in `read_excel` function, in my opinion.  See that if you can use some other library to read this filetype

Comment: @AnilGoyal I think so too. But the openxls package is also not working

Comment: I will recheck and return if something helpful is found.  I have bookmarked this too.